# How To Specify the fields to Wordpress API v2

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using the WordPress REST API in my project and sending a GET request to:

```
http://myblog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

and It's working quite alright but I want to specify the fields though I don't know how. I have looked at the documentation and still don't know how to go about it.  For example, using the public API:

```
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.mysite.com/posts?number=100&fields=title,excerpt,featured_image
```

returns only the specified fields. How do I this with the v2 API?

Comment: http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/modifying/

Comment: What don't you get? The REST API v2 returns a certain set of default fields, and if you want different ones, then you have to _implement_ this as described in that document.

Comment: Don't have access to the client's CP. I was hoping I could do that straight from the URL.

Answer (score 29):

Here's how to access the a list of titles and excerpts using REST API v2:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields[]=title&_fields[]=excerpt&per_page=100&offset=100
```

Comment: [Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#_fields)

Comment: It also accepts request like this:
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=title,excerpt&per_page=100&offset=100

Comment: @Hardik, thanks for the great shortcut there!

Comment: update: it works with v3 too

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/

As it states there, the REST API v2 returns a certain set of default fields, and if you want different ones, then you have to *implement* this as described in that document.

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution to this issue would be to use the [ACF to REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/) or an equivalent plugin that can extend the REST API for you. I have used this plugin on many sites successfully.

If this is not possible then you will need to modify the response as has been outlined by other answers. You can read more about that [here](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/modifying/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use ?_fields[]=title&_fields[]=excerpt

Comment: Isn't it already the solution given by [@mattmaldre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63102526/2227743) ?